# Viewing Firefox history by device when using Firefox Sync

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

Is there a way to filter history that is synced by Firefox Sync on the desktop version of Firefox to limit to a specific Firefox Sync device?  The Android app does this (though it seems to truncate the history).

Comment: Why would you want to? The whole purpose of syncing is to have identical entries on all versions.

Comment: Different devices used for different purposes.